# How can I sort a list by matching the words of another list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of strings like this:

```py
x = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Coconut']
y = ['Banana', 'Coconut', 'Apple']
```

How can I sort the Y-list so that it matches the order of the X-list by matching the words to get the following output:

```py
y = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Coconut']
```

Can I also make it so that if the Y-list is not equally long as the X-list, it would still sort the content? Like the following example:

```py
x = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Coconut']
y = ['Coconut', 'Apple']

#Output
y = ['Apple', 'Coconut']
```

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"]
y = ["Coconut", "Apple"]

y.sort(key=x.index)
print(y)
```

Prints:

```
['Apple', 'Coconut']
```

---

EDIT: The [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures) returns zero-based index of first item found in list. So `x.index("Coconut")` returns `2` and `x.index("Apple")` returns `0` - so we sort based on that number.

Comment: An explanation wouldn't be considered an extra

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And by looking at the code, I think I get it. The Y-list sorts the content based on the index numbers from the X-list. That way, it always matches the content. I'll accept your answer when the option is available. :)

Comment: Added small explanation of what the key function does.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, saw that now. Thanks!